# Does the navigation through result set depend on driver type being used?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, resultset

Suppose am using a driver and am doing a DB call to fetch some data. I store the data in the resultSet.

My question is, does the traversing through the resultSet formed from the DB call, depend on the diver ?
If we could do only forward only traverse or direction insensitive traversing and all depend on the type of driver being used ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes support for ResultSet types depends on the driver. All JDBC drivers are required to support `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, all other ResultSet types are optional: some databases don't support scrolling and driver implementers don't always want to simulate that by retrieving all rows and keeping them in memory driverside (not to mention the potential of exhausting all available memory that way).

Comment: That comes as a big surprise to me and thanks for clarifying on the same.

Comment: Can you provide some links to few materials reg this topic ?

Comment: Sure, look at the JDBC 4.1 spec (specifically section 6.3) http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-eval-spec/index.html